# Stacking of two linear-gradient backgrounds on one element but with different colours and heights

Tags: css, background, linear-gradients

I'm very new to trying fancy CSS effects but I'm after something quite particular and tricky and I'm having trouble finishing.

**This is the effect I'm looking for:**

[image]

It's a background effect for a `<div>` element. It's simply (or not simply for me) two stacked `linear-gradient` backgrounds that create equally-spaced, vertical pinstripes with different fill colours. The top background is a fixed 700px high and the bottom should be fluid i.e. repeated to fill the remaining space. The finished rule must be cross-browser i.e. the right prefixes, etc.

It could be that this isn't possible but I have read a little about people using multiple backgrounds/background stacking, so I thought that is what's needed to make this work.

I saw this effect on an Envato Market template but they used 10 empty `div` elements to make this work (one for the first colour, one for the second, eight for the vertical sections and many absolute positioned elements over many layers), which I don't think is a great idea hence wanting a simple CSS version.

**This is how far I've got before becoming stuck:**

```
background: linear-gradient(90deg, #E0E0E0 0.5%, transparent 0.5%) 0.5px 0, #EBF1F6;
background-size: calc((100% / 8) + 0.2px) 0.5px;
background-position: -1px;
```

**What I've done semi-explained:**

- The `linear-gradient` part consists of a 90deg gradient with an `#EBF1F6` fill and a `#E0E0E0` pinstripe.
- I used 0.5% to make the pinstripe the ideal thickness.
- I used `calc((100% / 8) + 0.2px)` to create 8 equally-spaced blocks and `0.2px` so that the pinstripe that is created at the right edge of the browser isn't visible (0.2px * 8 = shifts patterns to right by 1px).
- I similarly used `background-size: -1px` to get rid of the furthest left pinstripe at the left edge of the browser.

**This is how it looks so far:**

https://codepen.io/PaparazzoKid/pen/NWKOQZr

**What's missing:**

- I haven't managed to successfully set a height to the `linear-gradient` i.e. `700px`.
- Because I haven't set the first `linear-gradient`'s height, I obviously haven't tried stacking another `linear-gradient` to this element with a fluid height and different fill colour.
- It's not cross-browser and I'm pretty certain `linear-gradient` doesn't work for all browsers, as some need prefixes and some use `gradient` instead of `linear-gradient`.

I would be eternally grateful if somebody could share their knowledge and help me finish this CSS effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like below:

I used `80px` instead of `700px` so we can see the result in the reduced snippet. I also considered different number of vertical pinstripes to show that you can easily change them for each section:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to right,
      blue calc(100% - 2px), red calc(100% - 2px) 100%)      left top
      /calc((100% + 2px)/4)  80px,
    linear-gradient(to right,
      orange calc(100% - 2px), purple calc(100% - 2px) 100%) left bottom
      /calc((100% + 2px)/6) calc(100% - 80px);
   background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

In case you want a *gradient* instead of solid color between the vertical lines you can consider more gradient:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  background:
   /* Top layer*/
    linear-gradient(to right,
      transparent calc(100% - 2px), red calc(100% - 2px) 100%)      left top
      /calc((100% + 2px)/4)  80px,
    linear-gradient(60deg,blue,lightblue) left top/100% 80px,   
      
   /* Bottom layer*/   
    linear-gradient(to right,
      transparent calc(100% - 2px), purple calc(100% - 2px) 100%)  left bottom
      /calc((100% + 2px)/6) calc(100% - 80px), 
    linear-gradient(160deg,orange,green) left bottom/100% calc(100% - 80px);
   background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

With some CSS variable to easiy control the values:

```css
body {
  --nt:4;   /* Number of vertical lines on the top*/
  --lt:2px; /* Thickness*/
  
  --nb:6;   /* Number of vertical lines on the bottom*/
  --lb:4px; /* Thickness*/
  
  --h:100px; /*height of the top part*/

  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  background:
   /* Top layer*/
    linear-gradient(to right,
      transparent calc(100% - var(--lt)), red calc(100% - var(--lt)) 100%)      left top
      /calc((100% + var(--lt))/var(--nt))  var(--h),
    linear-gradient(60deg,blue,lightblue) top/100% var(--h),   
      
   /* Bottom layer*/   
    linear-gradient(to right,
      transparent calc(100% - var(--lb)), purple calc(100% - var(--lb)) 100%)  left bottom
      /calc((100% + var(--lb))/var(--nb)) calc(100% - var(--h)), 
    linear-gradient(160deg,orange,green) bottom/100% calc(100% - var(--h));
   background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

Also note that in case of solid coloration, you don't need to define the height of the bottom part since it will get overlapped by the top one

```css
body {
  --nt:4;   /* Number of vertical lines on the top*/
  --lt:2px; /* Thickness*/
  
  --nb:6;   /* Number of vertical lines on the bottom*/
  --lb:4px; /* Thickness*/
  
  --h:100px; /*height of the top part*/

  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  background:
   /* Top layer*/
    linear-gradient(to right,
      transparent calc(100% - var(--lt)), red calc(100% - var(--lt)) 100%)      left top
      /calc((100% + var(--lt))/var(--nt))  var(--h),
    linear-gradient(60deg,blue,lightblue) top/100% var(--h),   
      
   /* Bottom layer*/   
    linear-gradient(to right,
      transparent calc(100% - var(--lb)), purple calc(100% - var(--lb)) 100%)  left bottom
      /calc((100% + var(--lb))/var(--nb)) 100%, 
    linear-gradient(160deg,orange,green) ;
   background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is awesome!! I just played with what you provided and it works flawlessly and a lot better than what I had. I take it using `linear-gradient` alone is sufficient for cross-browser support now?

Comment: @MartinJames yes linear-gradient alone is sufficient for cross-browser. You simply need to pay attention to the support of calc() and CSS variable in case you will be using my last code

Comment: Of course. I'm using SASS, so I think variables are taken care of. Brilliant answer, thank you!

Comment: I do have one very slight issue. If you check my Codepen (https://codepen.io/PaparazzoKid/pen/NWKOQZr), you can see that not all pinstripes are equal widths. On my website, every other pinstripe is 2px and others 1px. In the Codepen, it's just the middle pinstripe that is different slightly. Is this easily fixable?

Comment: @MartinJames I don't see the issue, it's probably an optical illusion? or you have zoom activated

Comment: My zoom is 100%. However, if I resize the browser window the issue goes away depending on the size. So it depends on the size of the browser window as to what the exact widths of pinstripes are. If you have any suggestions as to why or have a quick fix, I'd love to hear them, otherwise, I will try and look into it more.